# Lint: "Errors/Warnings were listed in the baseline but not found in the project" multiple times

Tags: android, jenkins, gerrit, lint, sonatype

I develop an App for Android and use Gerrit and Jenkins with Lint.

The Workflow is: Push to Gerrit -> Start Build on Jenkins -> Verify via Lint.

My threshhold for Lint warnings is 1 and normally I had no problem reaching it. 
Now, after a bigger change I get 4 errors/warnings, from which each 2 are the same:

1. 2 errors/warnings were listed in the baseline file (lint-baseline.xml) but not found in the project; perhaps they have been fixed? Unmatched issue types: ApplySharedPref, ObsoleteLintCustomCheck
2. 1 errors/warnings were listed in the baseline file (lint-baseline.xml) but not found in the project; perhaps they have been fixed? Unmatched issue types: ApplySharedPref
3. 56 errors and 2 warnings were filtered out because they are listed in the baseline file, lint-baseline.xml
4. 56 errors and 1 warning were filtered out because they are listed in the baseline file, lint-baseline.xml

So my build fails as I exceed the threshhold by 3.

I created a new Lint baseline, but the errors stay the same. I also checked if the new baseline file on Jenkins did match the newly created one and it does.

My questions:

1. Why do I get these errors? Especially the first two, even if I created a new baseline directly before running the Build
2. Why are the (equally typed) Errors not grouped together?

Of course I could raise the threshhold but that does not make me understand what the Errors are ;)

Comment: I have the same issue, @HexFlex did you found a fix?